# Should a entire bathroom circuit run from a GFCI outlet

Tags: electrical, bathroom, gfci

I have a bathroom that is on its own circuit that feeds power from the panel to a GFCI receptacle and then feeds 2 lights and the bathroom fan.

So if the GFCI trips the lights and the fan goes out as well. I think this is OK, but I want to confirm there is no code violation. I am in Canada.

Comment: I think the question should be could you run everything on 1 gfi circuit. Under the NEC the lights do not require GFCI protection but all the receptacles do require GFCI protection, I normally run the lights then to a GFCI so if the GFCI trips it is local and you still have lights to see to reset it. But many homes are wired with the GFCI in the main panel and the lights are included so they go out.  I would say the lights should be prior to the GFCI but code allows both ways.

Comment: Does this circuit feed any other bathrooms?

Comment: No it's on its own circuit

Comment: Thanks Ed. That makes sense, and if I would've done it that's the way it would be wired. I'm most likely going to leave it since it's done already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That very typically happens when Goober wires it. (I don't know who Goober's Canadian cousin is, maybe Joe Gongshow?)

Joe hooks it up, and goes "hey, what do I do with these extra wires?  Oh look, 2 more screws under this warning tape I did not read".

Things should only be put on the LOAD screws if you really want to provide GFCI protection to them.  Otherwise, the LINE screws usually are able to accept 2 wires via screw-and-clamp.

Lights and fans do not need to be on GFCI unless they are inside the shower.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the way it is setup.  It ain't broke, don't fix it.